# What is the word for talking to someone as if they don't know anything

Tags: single-word-requests

This is noticeable in conversation when person A keeps trying to educate the person B. Person A automatically assumes a position of higher knowledge. What is person A doing to person B? It's not patronizing is it, because he isn't necessarily trying to talk to the other person in a condescending manner.

Comment: *High and mighty* can sometimes be used in this sort of context.

Comment: It's difficult to visualize a person talking to someone else as if that second person "didn't know anything," without getting the impression that the first person was condescending to the second. The situation would be quite different if the first person were simply supplying details or background information that the second person might not know, while generally treating the second person as an intellectual equal.

Comment: @SvenYargs It doesn’t necessarily have to be quite so clean-cut. When I get to talking to people about reconstruction Proto-Indo-European on the basis of cognates in various obscure, ancient languages, I generally do talk to them as if they know nothing—because usually, they don’t. I sincerely hope I’m not automatically being condescending towards them. Condescension only necessarily comes into the picture if _person A_ **always** talks to others like they don’t know anything. Then it’s hard to avoid coming off at condescending, I’ll give you that.

Comment: I don't know anything about reconstruction Proto-Indo-European on any basis, so your condescension (in the "descending to a lower level of discourse to become understandable" sense rather than in the patronizing sense) would be entirely appropriate. But you're right that speaking from a position of superior knowledge need not take the form of arrogance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several words depending on the context. When you say,

> person A keeps trying to **educate** person B

It can mean that Person A genuinely had more factual information and it was actually a  dialogue between Person A and B, then Person A could be **educative** or **informative**.

If on the other hand it was one-way traffic and Person A was speaking far more than Person B, then Person A was trying to **edify** Person B and Person A would be a **pedagogue** or a **pedant**; the latter if Person A was being persnickety.

If Person A was condescending to Person B, only in that case would Person A be **patronizing** Person B.

Comment: Yes; the appropriate term is situation-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Person A could be trying to **mentor** person B in a particular subject

- perhaps A is seeking to **evangelize** a particular technology or religion
- or A has a **pedagogical** nature
- A enjoys being in an **advisory** capacity to others, maybe going so far as dispensing **unsolicited advice**

Answer (score 0):

It's not one word, but "know-it-all" would describe the situation.

Definition:  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/know-it-all

Comment: A bit more detail, an explanation? A citation?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like person A is *talking down* to (or *patronizing* or acting *condescending* toward) person B.

Comment: OP: "It's not patronizing is it, because he isn't necessarily trying to talk to the other person in a condescending manner."

Answer (score -3):

If I were Person B, and I did not appreciate Person A's tone or agree with the assumption that Person A was my intellectual superior, I would say

> Stop lecturing me.

There are no dictionary definitions I can find that distinguish this usage from the neutral meaning of lecture, but it is one example of an ironic rhetorical device in which a speaker is rebuked for taking on a role they don't really have, ie.

- A non-actor delivering a *soliloquy*
- A layperson delivering a *sermon*