# What do you call someone who thinks everyone is incompetent (doesn't know anything)?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, pejorative-language

I'm looking for a way to describe someone who thinks everyone is incompetent (that is, doesn't know anything) and always has to explain every minute (small) detail because his perception of the person's competence is that it's very low (thinking the person is not that smart).

If this person were here, he'd probably end this post with...

> P.S. *To answer the question go to the bottom of the page, type in the answer, and then hit submit. I should be able to see it relatively quickly.*

How would you describe somebody like that?

Comment: Related: [What is the word for talking to someone as if they dont know anything?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195068/what-is-the-word-for-talking-to-someone-as-if-they-dont-know-anything/195116#195116)

Comment: First, I have to ask whether this is situational: does the person act that way with everyone, on every subject, or is it only in particular situations where he might reasonably be assumed to have expertise that the other person does not?

Comment: This word is an action so I'll leave it as a comment. And it does not connotes condescendence but [*baby talk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_talk) "frequently displays hyperarticulation" according to Wikipedia.

Comment: "Incompetent" doesn't mean "doesn't know anything" or "not that smart". Competence is about ability to perform tasks, not knowledge or intelligence.

Comment: Can someone higher-rep roll back the edit? Normally I'm in favor of removing "commentary/irrelevant" portions of questions, but the excised postscript not only added humor, but demonstrated the behavior in question.

Comment: When that person considers everyone incompetent, does that person include him/herself in "everyone"? Most of the answers assume that the answer to that is "no". You'd probably get very different responses if the answer to that is "yes".

Comment: The word "douchebag" comes to mind.

Comment: Do you know that there is a single word for this and can't remember it, or would you just like a good way to say this, and shorter is better? Also, from your description, I think 'patronizing' is perfect but since you don't think so already, can you add to your request anything extra that would rule out 'patronizing'?

Comment: Can you please explain why other answers don't fit also?

Comment: you mean, like someone who condescends to explain to you that "minute" can mean "small"?! How is you newt doing? Mine is doing just fine…

Comment: @RogueShakuras, please edit the question to make it clearer that you are looking for an adjective.  Thanks.

Comment: My favorite unsympathetic/sarcastic term for such a person is _unrecognized genius_. Matt Groenig (who later created _The Simpsons_) drew [this great cartoon](https://mlkshk-ada.kxcdn.com/r/29DS) about the type. My favorite moment is when the unrecognized genius is watching some TV game show and correctly answers a trivia question about Fred Flintstone that the contestant doesn't know the answer to—and then snarls, "Idiot. Those prizes are rightfully mine."

Comment: The P.S. joke was lost on me, you have 50 rep and been a member for 12 days. That information is superfluous to most users here but for not anyone with less 'cred'. Your example might be a condescending joke, however it could also be very helpful for us *grandpaws*. I'd have to hear your tone to decide if you're being condescending, narcissistic or actually trying to be helpful. Then I'd have to decide if you're just trying to *shine me on* (again ;)

Comment: Such a person could also be... German?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compulsive need to exolain everything in the minutest detail is contained in the rhetorical term *Epexegesis*

> **epexegesis (ɛˌpɛksɪˈdʒi:sɪs)**  **[(Collins)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/epexegesis)**    *(plural) -ses  (-,si:z)  (rhetoric)*
>
> 1. the addition of a phrase, clause, or sentence to a text to provide further explanation
> 2. the phrase, clause, or sentence added for this purpose
>
> [Example](http://biblehub.com/deuteronomy/5-21.htm): *' his field or his male servant or his female servant, his
> ox or his donkey or anything that belongs to your neighbour'* is an
> epexegesis of *'your neighbour's house* (beth).'

Epexegetic, and epexegetical, are formed regularly. On the analogy of Athlete from Athletic, the perpetrator of obsessive explanation is an epexegete: (cf. 'exegete' n.)

> **epexegete  (ɛˌpɛksɪˈdʒi:t)** **[(hapaxlegomenon)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word)**
>
> (noun)  a person who provides minutely detailed explanation.

That doesn't cover the [infantilizing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/infantilize) attitude this person shows to those around; but it sort of describes the obsession that is so annoying.

> **infantilizing**: treating someone as if that person were a child, with
> the result that they start behaving like one: [(Cambridge online)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/infantilize)

Now, a few years later (2021), 'mansplaining'would have to be included in a complete answer to this question. [(Merriam Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/mansplaining-definition-history)

Comment: IMO, this hasn't truly become English; it's still Greek. Colloquial? certainly not. Plus one all the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I feel this response fits the closest to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 45):

"Having to explain every minute detail" is not explicit in the definition of the word, but it is the sort of behavior you might expect from someone who

> ***[patronizes](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/patronize)***: speak to or behave toward someone as if they are stupid or not important

other people.

That particular meaning works with the verb form (patronize) and adjective form (patronizing). *Patronizer* is out there, but it seems to get more use for denoting someone who engages in the more pleasant sort of patronizing (sponsoring, supporting, or bringing trade to). If you're willing to accept a phrase rather than a single word, you could describe someone as a "patronizing overexplainer."

If you're just looking for an adjective, another suitable word is

> ***[haughty](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haughty)***: having or showing the insulting attitude of people who think that they are better, smarter, or more important than other people

though its definition also lacks the specific detail of feeling the need to explain minutiae to others.

P.S. I included links for the questioner because *common* search engines apparently proved too difficult. Positioning the mouse cursor over the red letters in italics and left-clicking with the mouse will open the pages with the quoted definitions.

Comment: "He is [so bloody] *patronizing*", fits better than "The boss patronizes everybody." And I realize your P.S is written in jest.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Agreed. The verb form has some ambiguity to it (excepting a negative statement: "Don't patronize me!"), but if we say someone is patronizing, the meaning is clear.

Comment: I really like this answer, but the biggest issue for me is that those words don't encompass the fact that the person goes into excessive detail. I've had a lot of trouble trying to find a word that describes just that. Someone who patronizes or has a haughty attitude, but shows these character traits by explicitly going into excessive detail.

Comment: @RogueShakuras Yes, that's why I added in the "patronizing overexplainer" to try to be inclusive of that point. But it's not a very appealing phrase, is it? Doesn't neatly roll off the tongue like a good phrase for someone/something like this should.

Comment: What about just 'overexplainer'? If they're always explaining everything more than necessary, that at least *implies* the attitude toward others' intelligence levels.

Comment: Lol, I see what you did in "P.S." paragraph

Answer (score 38):

I can't think of a good phrase for this, but if you are looking for descriptors, the two that come to mind are **condescending** and **belittling**.

Though these don't specifically incorporate this person's perception of the lack of knowledge of those he is belittling, at least they describe the resulting behavior.

Comment: Condescension *does* imply that the one condescending believes the one they're condescending to doesn't understand or know the fundamental ideas behind the concept (being condescended over? I think that's the right wording). It's for this reason I believe this answer most closely fits the asker's needs.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you're looking for the [Dunning-Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) effect?

"The Dunning–Kruger effect is a cognitive bias wherein unskilled individuals suffer from illusory superiority, mistakenly assessing their ability to be much higher than is accurate. This bias is attributed to a metacognitive inability of the unskilled to recognize their ineptitude. Conversely, highly skilled individuals tend to underestimate their relative competence, erroneously assuming that tasks that are easy for them are also easy for others."

Comment: I'm trying to work out if it's safe to upvote.

Comment: This doesn't apply; the "someone" of the OP might well be competent themselves and might assume tasks that are easy for them are *hard* for others.

Answer (score 8):

What about **pontifical**? Google defines it as *characterized by a pompous and superior air of infallibility*.

Comment: This is very good. Though I suppose it focuses more on the feeling of the person believing they are right, than denigrating others for being wrong.

Comment: It perpetuates anti-catholic discourse, though, so I'm gonna have to -1.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer If the discourse makes valid points, then there is no reason to censor it. While this answer isn't really correct for the question being asked, pontifical is a good word for anyone's vocabulary. Your -1 seems rather unfair so all I can do is +1 to balance things out.

Comment: This perpetuates anti-catholic discourse, though, so I'm gonna have to +1 (aside from the fact that "this answer is useful").

Answer (score 7):

A [**know-it-all**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Know-it-all)? Doesn't literally fit your definition, but does imply it, as someone who is convinced that they know everything and have all the answers is by extension likely to think that everyone else doesn't.

Comment: I like this, it would be better if we had a "know-better-than-you" or similar!

Answer (score 3):

**Pedant** might apply. According to Wikipedia A pedant is a person who is excessively concerned with formalism, accuracy, and precision, or who makes an ostentatious and arrogant show of learning.

Comment: ...with the added flexibility of pedantry, pedantic.

Answer (score 3):

One adjective similar to many already mentioned, but which carries a sense of the tendency to administer to inferior intellects and to lecture, is

> **self-righteous** 1. piously self-assured and smugly moralistic

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-righteous))

Looking into the definition, *moralstic* is defined as:

> characteristic of or relating to a narrow-minded concern of the morals of 
>   others

([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moralistic))

So as a descriptive term, *self-righteous* includes the notion that the person described, in being "piously," or intractably, "self-assured," most often would unjustifiably assume the inferiority of others' opinions and intellects. And in being "moralistic," the self-righteous person more often than not, whether out of a skewed notion of benevolence or just a desire to hurt someone's feelings, would attempt to correct the other's perceived faulty reasoning. This could extend to general criticism of of a person's competence, as opposed to restricting it to moral concerns.

Answer (score 3):

[Superiority Complex](http://counsellingcentral.com/alfred-adler-the-inferiority-and-superiority-complex/): An exaggerated feeling of being superior to others. A psychological defense mechanism which allows an individual to overcome or conceal feelings of inferiority.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you twist it you can adjust your phrasing by saying "he acted superior towards his employees" or "being around this person gives me a false sense of inferiority"

But I believe the best word that comes to mind would be "Elitist", as it would also go along side with other words that describe its attitude towards other people and view on self.

> *Adjective*
>
> 1. (of a person or class of persons) considered superior by others or by themselves, as in intellect, talent, power, wealth, or position in society:
>      *elitist country clubbers who have theirs and don't care about anybody else.*
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/elitist)

Comment: Welcome to the site @Juksefantomet! Have you thought of building your answer around the single word 'superior', since the question is looking for a single word rather than a pithy phrase?

Comment: I just logged in for the first time since i created my account, and to my surprise i discovered i had submitted a post a loong time ago. @EleventhDoctor sorry for ignoring that reply all in all 2 years ago! But her, better late then never right?

Comment: This made me smile @jukse! Don't worry, you're forgiven - I'm still here 2 years on :-)

Answer (score 2):

'Conceited' could be a good candidate for what you are looking for.

Someone who thinks they are so clever that they can do no wrong and everyone else does not measure up to their superiority.

Answer (score 2):

[overweening](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overweening) (ˌəʊvəˈwiːnɪŋ Pronunciation for overweening  )

adjective

1.(of a person) excessively arrogant or presumptuous

2.(of opinions, appetites, etc) excessive; immoderate

Answer (score 2):

> He was very blank, where it would be completely clear that it includes the viewing other people as incompetent and going into extreme detail.

I'll offer a few ideas to choose from: Dismissive, superior, egotistical, domineering, disdainful, dismissive, narcissistic, asshole (sorry -- this one is not an adjective), dogmatic, supercilious, overbearing, having an inflated sense of his own worth/intelligency/abilities, alienated by his own inflated opinion of himself, disrespectful, belittling, too smart for his own good, hypercritical, snobbish, above everybody else, insufferable, and as someone already said, pedantic.

---

Interfering, nitpicky. Incapable of delegating.  This one isn't an adjective, but you could say that he breathes down everyone's neck.  Backseat driver.

---

Control freak.  This means everything has to be done just so, and he can't allow anyone any autonomy or initiative.  There is an adjective for this: controlling.

Comment: *narcissistic asshole*; no comma. +1.

Comment: "[Narcissistic personality disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_personality_disorder) is characterized by an **over-inflated sense of self-importance**, as well as dramatic, emotional behavior that is in the same category as antisocial and borderline personality disorders. In addition to these symptoms, the person may **display arrogance, show superiority**, and seek power." –Wiki

Comment: It's like you're throwing everything at the wall to see what sticks. But some of those words are very good. +1

Comment: @mbnyc, you're right! I'm just brainstorming.  It can be hard to tell which word is going to satisfy that itch for a word that the OP has.

Answer (score 1):

There's **contemptuous**, from (of course) "contempt", which Merriam-Webster defines as  "[the] feeling that someone or something is not worthy of any respect or approval".

Answer (score 1):

I would call such a person **smug**. But it seems a bit of an understatement. 
**Holier-than-thou** is also a good way of putting it.

Answer (score 1):

**didactic** (*adj.*):

1. (*mainly disapproving*) intended to teach, especially in a way that is too determined or eager, and often fixed and unwilling to change

> '*a didactic approach to teaching*'

Source: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org)

2. (i) intended to teach, particularly in having moral instruction as an ulterior motive

   (ii) in the manner of a teacher, particularly so as to appear patronising

> '*his tone ranged from didactic to backslapping*'

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 1):

The word *[pedantic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedantic)* can mean "ostentatious in one's learning," always showing off and lording it over others who are less knowledgeable.

Actually, "lording it over," might not be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related: a **[misanthrope](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misanthrope)** is a person who basically hates the whole human race.  In my experience, most misanthropes are misanthropes because they think that almost everyone is stupid.  (That's my reason, anyway.)

Comment: Yes, this might be what the OP is looking for -- but let's make it an adjective: misanthropic.

Answer (score 0):

I would call that person **Laurence J. Peter**, who originated the Peter Principle: "managers rise to the level of their incompetence." He studied managerial psychology and observed that all people are promoted until they reach a position at which they are incompetent, at which point they are no longer promoted.

In other words, I would call someone who thinks everyone is incompetent "Correct".

Comment: This is side commentary and not an answer.  "Correct" means "right or accurate", not "thinks everyone is incompetent".

Comment: erm.. not "everyone" is a manager, though... (luckily)

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading your question...

> I'm looking for a way to describe someone who thinks everyone is
>   incompetent (i.e. doesn't know anything) and always has to explain
>   every minute (small) detail because his perception of the person's
>   competence is that it's very low (thinking the person is not that
>   smart).

... and I'm thinking I know people like this. A boss I used to have and a close relative, in particular.

So to answer your question I began by asking myself what these two people had in common that might make them this way.

Some characteristics they shared (in my estimation) were:

- deeply insecure about themselves
- frequently compensated for their insecurity by convincing themselves (subconsciously, perhaps) that others can't possibly be as smart as they are
- their treatment of others was a defensive maneuver designed (again, probably subconsciously) to protect their fragile ego

The words that come to mind when thinking of these people include:

> insecure, fragile, delusional, short-sighted and self-destructive

On a more superficial level (and maybe more relevant to the context of your question) I would say these people were:

> inconsiderate, rude and condescending

Comment: Your characteristics fit *narcissism* to a 'T'.

Comment: Absolutely right. A perfect fit. It didn't come to mind when I wrote my answer. I think I associate narcissism to a degree with jerks and a$$holes, and neither of these two people I referred to were fundamentally mean. In fact I felt sad for them. But you should post an answer with this word.

Comment: It is, [see here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259004/what-do-you-call-someone-who-thinks-everyone-is-incompetent-doesnt-know-anythi/261981#261981). Although it's buried. Most of your examples appear in other answers; take 'em all out and just use this ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd always go for ***supercilious*** in such contexts...

> **supercilious**  <sup>([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/supercilious) dictionary)</sup>
> *behaving as if you are better than other people, and that their opinions, beliefs, or ideas are not important*

Answer (score -1):

**indignant**

> adjective
>  feeling or showing anger or annoyance at what is
>   perceived as unfair treatment.

Comment: To feel you are being treated unfairly is not the same as believing everyone to be incompetent.

Answer (score -2):

> floccinaucinihilipilification

(often humorous) The act or habit of describing or regarding something as unimportant, of having no value or being worthless.

Comment: *Incompetent* is hardly the same thing as *worthless*.